# Height of data structures

Tags: data-structures, balanced-search-trees

Why the height complexity of a data structure, generally expressed in terms of $\log n$, do not contain a ceiling or floor ?

Comment: What is the "height complexity of a data structure"? Do you mean the height of a tree?

Comment: O(log n) = O(log n + 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotically, $\log n$ and $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$ (or $\lceil \log n \rceil$) are the same: a function is $\Theta(\log n)$ iff it is $\Theta(\lfloor \log n \rfloor)$. Therefore there is no need for floor or ceiling.

Comment: Thank you. I was talking about a non-asymptotic complexity.

Comment: If you want an exact number, then you should definitely use floor or ceiling. Otherwise, they are not necessary, since they only change the value by at most a constant (in fact, by at most 1).

Comment: Thank you @YuvalFilmus I was asking this question because sometimes I see (non asympotic) analysis in which the ceil or floor is omitted.

Comment: They are probably being a bit sloppy. It's nicer to the eyes without floors or ceilings.